# Thread 1: Fatal error: UnsafeMutablePointer.initialize overlapping range

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am trying to use

```
UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>?>!
```

as it is required for a parameter for a method i need to use. Yet I have no idea what this is or how to use it.

I created this value by doing this :

```
 var bytes2: [Float] = [39, 77, 111, 111, 102, 33, 39, 0]
    let uint8Pointer2 = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: 8)
    uint8Pointer2.initialize(from: &bytes2, count: 8)

    var bytes: [Float] = [391, 771, 1111, 1111, 1012, 331, 319, 10]
    var uint8Pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>?.init(uint8Pointer2)
    uint8Pointer?.initialize(from: &bytes, count: 8)

    let uint8Pointer1 = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>?>!.init(&uint8Pointer)
    uint8Pointer1?.initialize(from: &uint8Pointer, count: 8)
```

But I get the error :

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: UnsafeMutablePointer.initialize overlapping range
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating bad behaviour..

```
var bytes2: [Float] = [39, 77, 111, 111, 102, 33, 39, 0]
let uint8Pointer2 = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: 8)
uint8Pointer2.initialize(from: &bytes2, count: 8)
```

Creates a pointer to some memory and initializes that memory to the values stored in `bytes2`..

So:  `uint8Pointer2 = [39, 77, 111, 111, 102, 33, 39, 0]`

---

Then you decided to create a pointer that references that pointer's memory:

`var uint8Pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>?.init(uint8Pointer2)`

So if you printed `uint8Pointer`, it would have the EXACT same values as `uint8Pointer2`.. If you decided to change any of its values as well, it'd also change the values of `uint8Pointer2`..

So when you do:

```
var bytes: [Float] = [391, 771, 1111, 1111, 1012, 331, 319, 10]
uint8Pointer?.initialize(from: &bytes, count: 8)
```

It overwrote the values of `uint8Pointer2` with `[391, 771, 1111, 1111, 1012, 331, 319, 10]`..

---

So far, `uint8Pointer` is just a shallow copy of `uint8Pointer2`.. Changing one affects the other..

Now you decided to do:

```
let uint8Pointer1 = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>?>!.init(&uint8Pointer)
uint8Pointer1?.initialize(from: &uint8Pointer, count: 8)
```

Here you created a pointer (`uint8Pointer1`) to `uint8Pointer` and you said `uint8Pointer1` initialize with `uint8Pointer`.. but you're initializing a pointer with a pointer to itself and a count of 8..

First of all, don't bother calling initialize on a pointer to pointer with a value of itself.. It's already pointing to the correct values..

What's nice is that:

```
uint8Pointer1?.initialize(from: &uint8Pointer, count: 1)
//Same as:  memcpy(uint8Pointer1, &uint8Pointer, sizeof(uint8Pointer)`
//However, they both point to the same memory address..
```

will crash, but:

```
uint8Pointer1?.initialize(from: &uint8Pointer)
//Same as: `uint8Pointer1 = uint8Pointer`.. Note: Just a re-assignment.
```

won't.. because it doesn't do a `memcpy` for the latter.. whereas the former does.

Hopefully I explained it correctly..

P.S. Name your variables properly!

---

Translation for the C++ people:

```
//Initial pointer to array..
float bytes2[] = {39, 77, 111, 111, 102, 33, 39, 0};
float* uint8Pointer2 = &bytes[2];
memcpy(uint8Pointer2, &bytes2[0], bytes2.size() * sizeof(float));

//Shallow/Shadowing Pointer...
float* uint8Pointer = uint8Pointer2;
float bytes[] = {391, 771, 1111, 1111, 1012, 331, 319, 10};
memcpy(uint8Pointer, &bytes[0], bytes.size() * sizeof(float));

//Pointer to pointer..
float** uint8Pointer1 = &uint8Pointer;

//Bad.. uint8Pointer1 and &uint8Pointer is the same damn thing (same memory address)..
//See the line above (float** uint8Pointer1 = &uint8Pointer)..
memcpy(uint8Pointer1, &uint8Pointer, 8 * sizeof(uint8Pointer));
//The memcpy is unnecessary because it already pointers to the same location.. plus it's also wrong lol.
```